# Best practice for using scopes on already retrieved associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo

  def self.activated
    where(activated: true)
  end
end

class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @foos = Foo.includes(:bars)
  end
end
```

Let's say I want to display a table of all Foos, including the number of activated bars on it. To prevent N+1 queries, I already include(s) :bars when retrieving all Foos. However, If I use `foo.bars.activated`, Rails fires up another query, not knowing about the already retrieved bars.

I see two options here:

1. Instead of using a scope, filtering the already retrieved objects:
   `foo.bars.select(&:activated)`
2. Defining another custom association, scoped to activated bars: `has_many :activated_bars, -> { where(activated: true) }, class_name: 'Bar'`

Are there other (better) ways to do this?

Comment: Do you get the same result when you use `scope :activated, -> { where(activated: true) }` instead of `self.activated`?

Comment: yes, that's the exact same

Answer (score 1):

The following will load all foo's with only activated bars and also eager_load the bars

```
 Foo.eager_load(:bars).merge(Bar.activated)
```

Updated:

Or you might also define a new scoped relationship on Foo and eager_load that

```
#Foo
has_many :activated_bars, ->{ activated }, clas_name: 'Bar'

#foos_controller#index
Foo.includes(:activated_bars)
```

See also http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Comment: so would that be something you'd write in your index action?

Comment: Yes. I've also figured out another option and updated the answer